# Underlying C/C++ object has been deleted terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Swig::DirectorMethodException'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph, gnuradio

I am editing the top block for `qt` in GNURadio. When I generate a `qt` file, inside the top block I want to add a pyqtgraph `GraphicsWindow` which is created by my `Plot.py` block and is returned.
Here is the generated `top_block.py` :

```
class top_block(gr.top_block, Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block")
        Qt.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.top_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        self.top_scroll.setWidget(self.top_widget)
        self.top_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self.top_widget)
        self.top_grid_layout = Qt.QGridLayout()
        self.top_layout.addLayout(self.top_grid_layout)
```

Inside `Plot.py` I created a `pyqtgraphicsWindow` and returned the graphics window to `top_block.py` as shown

```
class Plot(gr.sync_block):
    def qtplot(self):
    print "inside qtplot"
    self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
    return self.win
```

In `top_block.py` I received and tried to add to `top_layout`:

```
 self.Plot_0 = gnuradio.input.Plot.Plot(1,1,1)
 self._plot_win=self.Plot_0.qtplot()
 self.top_layout.addWidget(self._plot_win)
```

However it is giving me a RuntimeError:

> underlying C/C++ object has been deleted terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Swig::DirectorMethodException'

I tried to add a `GraphicsWindow` directly in `init` of topblock and it worked fine.

Comment: @Luke any help would be appreciated

Comment: Notifying people that are not already in this discussion doesn't work in StackOverflow, Aakash. I accidentially found this, not because you wrote my Name in your comment. If you need to discuss something, I strongly recommend the mailing list, discuss-gnuradio@gnu.org . You need to sign up under https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio , where you also find the archives.

Comment: hm, SWIG errors are notoriously hard to debug. There has been some work on PyQt-based visualizations, I really think it's best if you write an email with a subject like "Trying to do PyQt-based visualization with python top_block", and link to the full source code of your module as well as the full text of your error.